# Recover software RAID

Tags: linux, software-raid, mdadm

I built a RAID-1 with two hard drives using mdadm. Command used was:

```
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
```

it went fine, I create partition table and partitions in it, mounted put some files there. Then I rebooted and realized I did not update `mdadm.conf`. How do I get my RAID back without losing data?

**Update**: results of `--examine` and `--assemble` commands:

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)

# mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
mdadm: Cannot assemble mbr metadata on /dev/sdb
mdadm: /dev/sdb has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

Does it make any difference that I created RAID on whole device instead of single partition?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would do something like this.

- Run the examine command against one of the member drives/partitions: mdadm --examine /dev/sdc`
- Look for the **Array UUID** value.
- Update your mdadm.conf with the array UUID value.

Something like this, using your UUID.

```
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=326e64b6:1af3dfb4:e1fc5d41:ebd329b0
```

Comment: See my update. There is no UUID in `--examine` output.